# modify html tags replace "src" with "data-src"

Tags: beautifulsoup

is there way to use `BeautifulSoup` to replace element tags for images, I have some HTML files that I want to replace the "src" with "data-src" of that img

```
<img src="//Pictures/q-90-90.png" data-src="//Pictures/p720_test.jpg">
```

code so far

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("template/home.html", 'lxml')
images = soup.findAll('img')
for i in images:
    #replace src with data-src
```

I am open to any solution using regex as well, Ideally the output would be

```
<img src="//Pictures/p720_test.jpg" data-src="//Pictures/q-90-90.png">
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex on html; try this instead:

```
soup.find('img')['src']= "data-src"
```

Edit:

To swap attribute values inside the `<img>` elements, try this:

```
old_src = soup.select_one('img')['src']
old_data = soup.select_one('img')['data-src']
target = soup.select_one('img')
target['src']= old_data
target['data-src']= old_src
```

Comment: this made the src for the first image only as `src="data-src"`

Comment: You only have on`<img>` element in your question, so I don't know what your real html looks like. Second, even for that element, I don't know why you get that output; in my case, the output is: `<img data-src="//Pictures/p720_test.jpg" src="data-src"/>`.

Comment: that is what I got with your answer, but it is not like the expected output where the values are "switched"

Comment: @goku So to be clear: you don't want to change the attribute name - you want to switch the attribute values of these two attributes?